# Problem Loading 7-ZIP Library with JEDI 7-ZIP Archive

Tags: exception, delphi, 7zip, jedi, delphi-12-athens

I'm trying to run the [7-ZIP compression example](https://github.com/project-jedi/jcl/tree/master/jcl/examples/windows/compression/archive) from [JEDI Code Library](https://github.com/project-jedi/jcl), but I keep getting this error:

> Project ArchiveDemo.exe raised exception class EJclCompressionError with message 'Cannot load sevenzip library'.

I definitely have JEDI Code Library installed into my IDE, because the code compiles and it sees all the units. I also definitely have 7-ZIP installed on my computer.

What is causing this exception? What does it mean by it "Cannot load sevenzip library"?

It is raised in the `UMain.pas` at these lines of code at the bottom of the file:

```
initialization

  if not Load7Zip then
    raise EJclCompressionError.Create('Cannot load sevenzip library');
```

Comment: Is it possible that you have 64 bit 7-zip, but compile 32 bit example app?

Comment: Put the 7zip DLL next to your exe